# How to solve claimitem() in batch process?

Tags: 8, batch-operations

I am doing batch process in D8.
here is my code:
This code is in **Controller.php**

```
$batch = array(
          'title' => t('Started Importing node Data.'),
          'error_message' => t('Error!'), //Error Message
          'finished' => 'node_data_import_batch_finished',
        );
        $count_nodes = '';
        $j = 0;
        $data_chunk = array_chunk($csv, 100);
        foreach ($data_chunk as $node_created) {
          $count_nodes += count($node_created);
          $batch['operations'][] = array('node_data_import_batch', array($node_created,  $keys));
          $j++;
        }
        batch_set($batch);
```

And callback function is in **.module**

```
function node_data_import_batch($node_created,  $keys){
//Code here
}

function node_data_import_batch_finished($success, $results, $operations){
 if ($success) {
    $message = "Batch Process Successfully executed for Node Data.";
    drupal_set_message($message);
  }
}
```

[image]

I am getting error like this.
Any help will be appreciable
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `'file'` key in your batch:

> - file: Path to the file containing the definitions of the 'operations'
>     and 'finished' functions, for instance if they don't reside in the
>     main .module file. The path should be relative to base_path(), and
>     thus should be built using drupal_get_path().

```
$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Started Importing node Data.'),
  'error_message' => t('Error!'), //Error Message
  'finished' => 'node_data_import_batch_finished',
  'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME') . '/YOUR_MODULE_NAME.module',
);
```